# Excel Vba Save file in pre-defined path based on static variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying change the below to actually instead asking the path it should save to pre-definied path based on static variable + dynamic variable from cell.

If the folder dosen't exist it should be created.

Cansomeone guide me how to change this as I'm not VBA guru and it I can't find right solution at all.

```
Sub Pdf_To_EMail()
Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range
Dim xStr As String
Dim xlSht As Excel.Worksheet

Set xSht = ActiveSheet
Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)

Else

MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"

Exit Sub
End If

xStr = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss")
xFolder = xFolder + "\" + xSht.Name + "-" + xStr + ".pdf"


If Len(Dir(xFolder)) > 0 Then

xYesorNo = MsgBox(xFolder & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", _
vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
On Error Resume Next
If xYesorNo = vbYes Then

Kill xFolder
Else

MsgBox "if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
& vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"

Exit Sub
End If
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file. Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." _

& vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"

Exit Sub
End If
End If

Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then

'Zapisz jako plik PDF

xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xFolder, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
With xEmailObj

.Display False
.To = "Email@Email.com"
.CC = ""
.Subject = "”
.Body = ":"
.Attachments.Add xFolder
If DisplayEmail = False Then
.Send
End If
End With
Else
MsgBox "The active worksheet cannot be blank"
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should Work:

Currently it will check for a Folder on Your Desktop and `Activesheet.Range("B2")`, But you can change both of them in the String Formation `xFolder`

```
Sub Pdf_To_EMail()
Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range
Dim xStr As String
Dim xlSht As Excel.Worksheet


Set xSht = ActiveSheet

''''New Code to detect if folder Exists

Dim objFSO As Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

xFolder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & xSht.Range("B2").Value '''' Change you path and cell Range

    If objFSO.FolderExists(xFolder) Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        objFSO.CreateFolder (xFolder)  '
    End If


xStr = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss")
xFolder = xFolder + "\" + xSht.Name + "-" + xStr + ".pdf"


If Len(Dir(xFolder)) > 0 Then

xYesorNo = MsgBox(xFolder & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", _
vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
On Error Resume Next
If xYesorNo = vbYes Then

Kill xFolder
Else

MsgBox "if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
& vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"

Exit Sub
End If
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file. Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"

Exit Sub
End If
End If

Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then

'Zapisz jako plik PDF

xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xFolder, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)

    With xEmailObj
        .Display False
        .To = "Email@Email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = "”"
        .Body = ":"
        .Attachments.Add xFolder
        If DisplayEmail = False Then
        .Send
        End If
    End With

Else
    MsgBox "The active worksheet cannot be blank"
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```